# Several animations are playing at the same when user clicks on multiple links, but I just want the last chosen one to be played. (beginner)

Tags: jquery

I've put a simple example online:

http://philiphannaart.nl/helpme/

When a user clicks on either of one of the three links an animation will start. 
It works if the user waits with his next click until the animation is complete. But if he's clicking fast on each link it gets all buggy and messed up. Any advice how to solve this or where to look for a solution?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not give the code you used for it.

but as i am assuming, you have to use **.stop()** to play your animation in your code when you are clicking on the buttons.

i have done something:

```
var anigone = function() {
    $("#oneb").stop().fadeOut(1000);
    $("#twob").stop().fadeOut(1000);
    $("#threeb").stop().fadeOut(1000);
    $("#one").stop().fadeIn(0);
    $("#two").stop().fadeIn(0);
    $("#three").stop().fadeIn(0);    
}

var red = function() {

    anigone();

    var red2 = $('#one');
    red2.stop().delay(1000).animate({
        left: 330 
    }, 1000, function() {
     red2.stop().fadeOut(1000);
     $("#oneb").stop().fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $("#two").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:480  }, 1000);
    $("#three").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:630  }, 1000); 
    $("#four").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:790  }, 1000);
}

var green = function() {

    anigone();

    $("#one").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:180 }, 1000);
    var green2 = $('#two');
    green2.stop().delay(1000).animate({
        left: 330 
    }, 1000, function() {
     green2.stop().fadeOut(1000);
     $("#twob").stop().fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $("#three").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:480  }, 1000); 
    $("#four").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:630 }, 1000);
}

var blue = function() {

    anigone();

    $("#one").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:30 }, 1000);
    $("#two").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:180 }, 1000);
    var blue2 = $('#three');
    blue2.stop().delay(1000).animate({
        left: 330 
    }, 1000, function() {
     blue2.stop().fadeOut(1000);
     $("#threeb").stop().fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $("#four").stop().delay(1000).animate({
    left:480 }, 1000);
}

$("#red").live('click', function() {
red();
});
$("#green").live('click', function() {
green();
});
$("#blue").live('click', function() {
blue();
});
```

​

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your effort and time!

Answer (score 0):

just write .stop() before every .animate() , .fadeIn() , .fadeOut()